# How to keep track or trace the elements of array in MFC c++ visual studio

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2012, mfc, trace

I'm fairly new to visual studios/window aplications, so im not used to not having a command line.

Basically I have for example a `CString m_storeEx = "12 + 2 - 4 "` and so I used tokenize method to put each number and operator into an array by doing this:

```
CStringArray arr;
CString resToken= m_StoreEx.Tokenize(_T(" "),curPos);    

while (resToken != _T(""))
{
    arr.Add(resToken);
    resToken = m_StoreEx.Tokenize(_T(" "), curPos);
}
```

I want the end result to be an array like this `arr = ['12', '+', '2', '-', '4']`

I just want to check if im adding the elements in right. Usually if I code with something that has a commandline, I'd just make a for loop, and print the array out to check. But I'd know to do that in MFC visual basics since there is no command line. I tried using the debugging tool to check the value of the array, but it just gave me weird numbers and letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by [l33t](https://stackoverflow.com/users/419761/l33t) in [his/her answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31854319/1889329), Visual Studio has provisions to extend and customize the visualization of objects in the debugger. Details are available under [Create custom views of native objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620914.aspx). By default, Visual Studio doesn't ship a `CStringArray` visualizer, so you are left with writing your own.

The following is a simple visualizer, that displays both the collection size as well as its contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AutoVisualizer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010">
  <Type Name="CStringArray">
    <DisplayString>{{size={m_nSize}}}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
      <ArrayItems>
        <Size>m_nSize</Size>
        <ValuePointer>m_pData</ValuePointer>
      </ArrayItems>
    </Expand>
  </Type>
</AutoVisualizer>
```

There are several ways to enable this visualizer. The easiest deployment is to copy the XML code above to a file (e.g. *CStringArray.natvis*) and copy that file to the directory `%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Visualizers\`. Other alternatives are documented in the link above.

Once deployed, stepping through the following code

```
CStringArray str;
str.Add( _T( "12" ) );
str.Add( _T( "+" ) );
str.Add( _T( "2" ) );
str.Add( _T( "-" ) );
str.Add( _T( "4" ) );
```

produces this visualization in the debugger:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you desperately need this feature, you could always [create a custom view](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620914.aspx) in Visual Studio.

1. Close Visual Studio.
2. Open the file `autoexp.dat` from [Visual Studio Installation Folder]\Common7\Packages\Debugger in `Notepad`.
3. Copy and paste the following code snippet into `autoexp.dat`. Specifically, paste it on the first line of the file.

   ```
   CStringArray{
       children
       (
           #array
           (
               expr : ($e.m_pData[$i]),
               size : ($e.m_nSize)
           )
       )
   }
   ```

Comment: Odd. You linked to the correct URL, describing how to implement *Natvis visualizations*, only to move on and provide a sample, that uses the undocumented, unsupported, and superseded autoexp.dat file. Reason?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the Visual Studio debugger cannot show the content of a CStringArray, but ther are some helper trace function that you can call:

```
...
while (resToken != _T(""))
{
    arr.Add(resToken);
    resToken = m_StoreEx.Tokenize(_T(" "), curPos);
}

afxDump.SetDepth(1);
arr.Dump(afxDump);
```

This will show the content of the `arr` array in the Visual Studio output window like this:

```
a CStringArray at $0032FB60
with 5 elements
    [0] = 12
    [1] = +
    [2] = 2
    [3] = -
    [4] = 4
```